# Using colspan and rowspan in same cell in HTML table

Tags: html, html-table

My default table looks like this, with 4 separate cells:

[image: See This Picture]

I want to create a table with this schema (merge r1c1 & r1c2 &r2c2):

[image: See This Picture]

My default table code is:

```html
<table border="2">
<caption style="border: 1px dotted;">Table 1</caption>
<tr>
<td>r1c1</td>
<td>r1c2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>r2c1</td>
<td>r2c2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And my merged table code look like this (but doesn't do what I wanted!):

```html
<table border="2">
<caption style="border: 1px dotted;">Table 1</caption>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" rowspan="2">r1c1 & r1c2 & r2c2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td >r2c1</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

How do I get those three cells merged using colspan and rowspan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot implement this with table cells. However, A similar layout can be displayed using css styles as shown in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/midhunadarvin/eey8ha7z/1/).

**html**

```
<table border="2">
    <caption style="border: 1px dotted;">Table 1</caption>
    <tr>
        <td id="r1c1" colspan="2">r1c1 & r1c2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>r2c1</td>
        <td id="r2c2" rowspan="2">r2c2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**css**

```
#r1c1 {
border: none !important;
}

#r2c2 {
border: none !important;
}
```

You can create a similar L shape using `div` tags by applying similar css styles as shown in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HwKGx/1/). Also you can refer this [link](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/) to find css styles for creating various shapes.